# POST request header versus request body for sensitive data in rest api

Tags: rest, api, security

i'm creating a simple rest API in PHP, I have 2 question:

1. is it any **security** difference between sending sensitive data (e.g., token) via request header and request body (in POST method) **over TLS** connection?
2. what if I use simple HTTP (no TLS) connection?

Answer (score -1):

1. No there is not
2. Then it isn’t secure

Comment: for the 2nd question, I meant is it any security difference between request body and request header in HTTP? or both are same (insecure)?

Comment: There isn’t a difference. It is just insecure.